# Strange DNS record duplication with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, dns

While recently working with the native Powershell DNS commandlets, specifically Get-DNSServerResourceRecord, I noticed something strange that does not make sense to me.

When I look into my zone using native DNS tools, LDAP query tools, or even ADSIedit, I see only a single DNS object representing a given hostname.

However, when I do the same with Powershell, I instead get **two** objects for a given host, one for the NETBIOS name, and the other for the FQDN.  All other attributes are the same, including the IP.

For example, if I had a computer named **computer1**:  This is what I see.

```
PS C:\> Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName 'mydomain.local' -RRType A -ComputerName 'DNSServer1' | Where-Object {$_.hostname -like "Computer1*"}  | fl *


DistinguishedName     : DC=computer1.mydomain.local,DC=mydomain.local,cn=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mydomain,DC=local
HostName              : COMPUTER1.mydomain.local
RecordClass           : IN
RecordData            : DnsServerResourceRecordA
RecordType            : A
Timestamp             :
TimeToLive            : 01:00:00
Type                  : 1
PSComputerName        :
CimClass              : root/Microsoft/Windows/DNS:DnsServerResourceRecord
CimInstanceProperties : {DistinguishedName, HostName, RecordClass, RecordData...}
CimSystemProperties   : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties

DistinguishedName     : DC=computer1,DC=mydomain.local,cn=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones,dc=mydomain,dc=local
HostName              : COMPUTER1
RecordClass           : IN
RecordData            : DnsServerResourceRecordA
RecordType            : A
Timestamp             :
TimeToLive            : 01:00:00
Type                  : 1
PSComputerName        :
CimClass              : root/Microsoft/Windows/DNS:DnsServerResourceRecord
CimInstanceProperties : {DistinguishedName, HostName, RecordClass, RecordData...}
CimSystemProperties   : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```

I'm so confused at why Powershell is showing this and where it's actually pulling it from.  I cannot locate those FQDN objects using native LDAP tools, even ADFind.

Is this some weird artifact/bug of the Powershell DNS cmdlets?  Or does DNS records store dual entries for a given host, but only display one using native tools?

Neither make sense to me, as I would not expect a cmdlet to just make up DN values on the fly, and this doesn't occur for **all** host records.The latter does not seem possible as this is not occurring for all records in the zone.  I have about 100 more records without the fqdn than with (10926 vs 10824).

**EDIT**  If it helps, here is an ADFind query for the same object (and wildcard).

```
C:\temp>adfind -h dnsserver1 -domaindns -f "(&(name=computer1*))" name

AdFind V01.57.00cpp Joe Richards (support@joeware.net) November 2021

Using server: dnsserver1.mydomain.local:389
Directory: Windows Server 2016
Base DN: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=ad,DC=ewsad,DC=net

dn:DC=computer1,DC=mydomain.local,CN=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mydomain,DC=local
>name: computer1


1 Objects returned
```

Comment: You didn’t show your other dns queries. Your powershell example looks for all records with a wildcard match. Are your other commands doing the same?

Comment: There are no other DNS queries.  I'm intentionally using a wildcard to pull all records related to that specific computer name,  

Note:  no records existed for Computer1 at the start of this.  In the DNS snapin I created a single DNS A record for Computer1, and the above two records are what actually got created (accordingly to Powershell, anyway).  No other tool shows the existence of the one with hostname=computer1.mydomain.local

Comment: Please see edited post where I included an ADFind query for the same hostname (with wildcard).

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm this behavior.

In powershell, this returns 2 results for many of the computers (maybe all, I didn't check)

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName 'domain.com' -RRType A -ComputerName dnserver1 | where hostname -like Computer1*

DistinguishedName     : DC=Computer1.domain.com,DC=domain.com,cn=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=com
HostName              : Computer1.domain.com
RecordClass           : IN
RecordData            : DnsServerResourceRecordA
RecordType            : A
Timestamp             : 12/8/2022 9:00:00 AM
TimeToLive            : 00:20:00
Type                  : 1
PSComputerName        :
CimClass              : root/Microsoft/Windows/DNS:DnsServerResourceRecord
CimInstanceProperties : {DistinguishedName, HostName, RecordClass, RecordData...}
CimSystemProperties   : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties

DistinguishedName     : DC=Computer1,DC=domain.com,cn=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=com
HostName              : Computer1
RecordClass           : IN
RecordData            : DnsServerResourceRecordA
RecordType            : A
Timestamp             : 12/8/2022 9:00:00 AM
TimeToLive            : 00:20:00
Type                  : 1
PSComputerName        :
CimClass              : root/Microsoft/Windows/DNS:DnsServerResourceRecord
CimInstanceProperties : {DistinguishedName, HostName, RecordClass, RecordData...}
CimSystemProperties   : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```

But a dsquery results in one record.

```
dsquery computer -name computer1* -s dnsserver1

"CN=Computer1,OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

You can confirm only one of these is a real AD object.

```
$recordlist = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName 'domain.com' -RRType A -ComputerName dnserver1 | where hostname -like Computer1*

foreach($record in $recordlist){
    Write-Host "Checking DN $($record.DistinguishedName)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    
    $found = $record.DistinguishedName |
        Get-ADObject -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if($found){
        Write-Host "Record found in AD" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Record not in AD" -ForegroundColor DarkGray
    }
}
```

So I must conclude thus far the evidence does indicate the `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord` is adding a duplicated record with the FQDN as well. Hopefully someone can find or knows why it was implemented in this manner.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation!  In my case it is not all records.